# "Welcome to (city name)!" used ironically by townspeople

Tags: story-identification

This incident was a small part of the adventures of the protagonist, which probably consisted of several to many books.

He'd heard of a city or town that was supposed to be very welcoming of strangers, in an otherwise unfriendly world or part of the world, so seeks it out for that or some other reason.

> Outsiders visiting the town are promptly enslaved, or sacrificed, or something along those lines. I think the hero is told "Welcome to (cityname)!" sarcastically as they're putting the chains on him (literally or figuratively).
>  Agents of the city actively spread the rumor that the place is a sanctuary in order to attract unknowing people there.
>  The hero of course escapes and/or overthrows the town's rulers.

I'm sure the stories were pulp, or planetary romance.  I would have read this in the early 80s.  Could it be John Carter maybe, or something by Lin Carter, or maybe one of the first few Gor books I waded through?

Comment: For those who might not realize, John Carter was a character in a series of books written by Edgar Rice Burroughs that were set on Mars (Barsoom); Lin Carter was an author who wrote adventure stories, like extensions of the Conan stories or his Venus novels; Gor was the name of a planet at the Earth-Sun L3 point in a series of stories written under the pseudonym John Norman (better known for their uncommon views on male/female relations).  Burroughs was done writing well before the 80s (died 1950), Carter was mostly done, and Norman was actively publishing.

Comment: @Brythan Well said, thanks for the additional information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is "Outlaw of Gor" by John Norman, the second book in his feminist(*) fantasy series. Details lifted from these two sites:

http://www.gor-now.net/delphius2002/id68.htm

http://www.oocities.org/goreansprings/Tharna.html

> Tharna was known for providing hospitality to strangers unlike most other cities. Most cities view strangers as enemies. But, Tharna had a sinister motive for such hospitality. Anyone who remained in the city for more than ten hours could never leave. They would become slaves working in the fields or the mines. Despite its open door policy, the city is not very inviting once you enter its gates.

And

> The man laughed bitterly. "How many hours, Warrior," asked he, "have you been within the walls of Tharna?"
>
> "At the sixth hour I came to Tharna," I said.
>
> "It is then too late," said the man, with a trace of sorrow, "for you have been within the walls for more than ten hours."
>
> I had been disturbed by this conversation and without really intending it had begun to walk to the walls. I stood before the great gate of Tharna. The two giant beams that barred it were in place, beams that could only be moved by a team of broad tharlarions, draft lizards of Gor, or by a hundred slaves. The gates, bound with their bands of steel, studded with brass plates dull in the mist, the black wood looming over me in the dusk, were closed.
>
> "Welcome to Tharna," said a guard, leaning on his spear in the shadows of the gate.

All other details match, including the enslavement, the escaping and overthrowing of the city's rulers.

(*) May not actually be feminist.

Comment: What a bizarrely specific timescale. You'd think that they'd just kidnap people on arrival.

Comment: @Valorum This is probably to allow trading and similar activities.

Comment: Feminist?  Are you kidding?  With lines like, "all women are happier being slaves, they just don't know it yet," those books are a far cry from feminist.  The first four (where the main character was fighting against that system) were OK but the rest of the series went far, far off the deep end after the main character bought into that philosophy..

Comment: @ShadoCat, it was meant as a joke. So, yes, I was kidding.

Comment: Might want an emoticon or something there.  Just say'in.

Comment: Or something, done.

Comment: Better to just not include the "joke" at all.

Comment: That's the one.  No wonder I had forgotten it.  Thanks!